# How to match specifics characters and exclude them when they follows a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to clean some data in a csv in python. But I have problem with my quotes in my csv, so I hope you can help me fix it with regex.

One line of my csv look like this :

`"""My name";"";"is";""Hello ; World"";"";`

Is it possible to match multiple quotes but make it so it does not match the quote that are between semicolons

```
"" -> match

""" -> match

;""; -> not match
```

Does anyone have a solution to my problem ? Thanks

Best regards.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at finding a regex pattern that solves your problem yourself?

Comment: Writing a regex to match your output is fairly easy, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking. What output do you want from the csv line you've given us?

Comment: I want to do the regex with the re.sub fonction from re python module.            
Input : """My name";"";"is";""Hello ; World"";"";                                                
Output : "My name";"";"is";"Hello ; World";"";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using positiv lookahead and lookbehind:

```
import re

s='"""My name";"";"is";""Hello ; World"";"";'                          

In: re.sub(r'(?<=[^;"])"+|"+(?=[^;"])',r'@',s)                             
Out: '@My name@;"";@is@;@Hello ; World@;"";'
```

Edit:

```
(?<=[^;"])"+    matches quotes not preceeded by other quotes or ;
 "+(?=[^;"])    matches quotes not followed by other quotes or ;
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that double quotes will always be besides the semi colons - its ok if that's the requirement.

Comment: @barry_allen You think whitespaces?

Comment: I guess this is good enough - whitespaces can be handled by \s*. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
ln = '"""My name";"";"is";""Hello ; World"";"";'
ln_arr = ln.split(";")
print(ln_arr)
for i, val in enumerate(ln_arr):
  if val != '""':
    ln_arr[i] = ln_arr[i].replace('""','')
print(ln_arr)
ln = ';'.join(ln_arr)
print(ln)
```

Output:

```
['"""My name"', '""', '"is"', '""Hello ', ' World""', '""', '']
['"My name"', '""', '"is"', 'Hello ', ' World', '""', '']
"My name";"";"is";Hello ; World;"";
```

Comment: Ignore the hello world color formatting - thats due to code parsing by stackoverflow'